# Selenium C# SwitchTo using directive or assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I am attempting to use driver.SwitchTo to access an iFrame embedded in my page and I am getting error: 'IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'switchTo' and no extension method 'switchTo' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Wondering which assembly reference or using directive I am missing.

These are the using directives I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Globalization;
```

These are the assembly references:

[image: error]

Comment: `C#` is case sensitive Did you try using `SwitchTo`? ? As per error message you are using `switchTo` (camel case).

Comment: Rookie error. Thank you very much, that's worked a treat.

Comment: No problem, happens some time in busy schedule. Will add this as an answer to help people with similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

`C#` is case sensitive, looking at the error issue could be due to missing case.

Use `SwitchTo` instead of `switchTo` (Notice Pascal case)